# SSRS - Report Expression

Tags: reporting-services

I am not sure how I am to explain what I want from the expression, but I hope you can see it through my expression otherwise I will try to explain.

```
=IIF(Fields!MyColumn.Value < (Fields!MyColumn2.Value -.5), "Red", "LightSteelBlue")
```

Basically, I want it to calculate the MyColumn2 -.5 then with this value, want to be compared to MyColumn1, and if the value in MyColumn is less, then give it red color, otherwise light steel blue color.

Still new to expressions and don't work with them very often. I am sure I am doing something wrong. If you are able to help out, that would be great!

Best

Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use sum() in your expression:

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!MyColumn.Value) < (Sum(Fields!MyColumn2.Value)-.5), "Red", "LightSteelBlue")
```